# Is there a (qnap-compatible) FTPS to SFTP proxy / bridge?

Tags: backup, proxy, sftp, qnap, ftps

From an FTP server on the internet, I'd like to download a folder structure in regular intervals onto my QNAP NAS, a TS-831X. Unfortunately, the NAS backup-tools only offer FTP(s) and the server on the internet only speaks SFTP.

- Ideally, this would be triggered by the NAS itself, so *no* external machine nor script pulling and pushing stuff required.
- I only need one single instance, so I could hard-code the respective server address somewhere. It does not need to scale to thousands of internet hosts.
- Having the ssh connection to the internet server open 24/7 is not an option, it should be closed after downloading (ftp "quit").
- I do not control the internet server, only `sftp` is available. No `scp`, no `webdav`, no plain `ftp`...

Is there an easy way to bridge / proxy the NAS' `ftps`-requests, perhaps to `localhost`, via `sftp` to the internet server transparently and close the connection after downloading all the files and folders? Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you run a container on it to perform the transfers?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the TS-831X is not nearly powerful enough to run virtual stuff.

Comment: That's not what the product page says.